# Are modifications to existing languages allowed as submissions?

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, answers

Say I have a language I'd love to use (like JavaScript for example), but there are tons of little pieces of functionality I'd love to modify built-ins with, like `.peek()` on arrays, or `.isPrime()` on numbers, etc. Assuming I kept a collection of utilities like this published on Github, would it be acceptable to write submissions like

## JavaScript (using `myutils.js`), [...] bytes

#### [...]

Another follow-up question I have to this is, if it *is* allowed, would submissions like this typically be well-received or no?

Assuming the collection of modifications had intuitive naming-conventions that might conceivably be used in production code if developers weren't opposed to modifying built-ins (which is a completely separate holy war in JavaScript), I have a hard time classifying something like this as "cheating".

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't be allowed, as long as you don't create short built-ins that exactly or almost exactly complete what is asked in a challenge after the challenge is posted/sandboxed.  While that wouldn't technically be against the rules, I would expect a flood of downvotes if you do so.  With that caveat, however, I believe it would be allowed to modify a language in this way (provided there's an implementation to run these built-ins, as @EriktheOutgolfer pointed out).

Comment: If there's an implementation for that then yes it's allowed.

Comment: @Gryphon I can't seem to find the question, but there was a meta post a few days ago I read, there was talk of removing the policy of answering pre-existing challenges with new implementations. Reading the feedback given there, I do understand this caveat pretty well and I think I could avoid coming across as "cheating" in those cases by making sure my submissions don't use updates that were applied after-the-fact.

Comment: As long as new built-ins don't solve most or all of a pre-existing (non-trivial) challenge, you should be good to go.

Comment: If you're specifically looking for a "golfier" version of JS with plenty of handy built-ins, might I recommend Japt? [Github project](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), [Interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/), [Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt), [Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121253/58974). EDIT: Not that I'm trying to discourage you from developing your own language, of course.